# C#, How to put command lines in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, richtextbox

I have two groups of richTextBox each group has 150 richTextBox, I use to send the output to the richTextBox as in bellow:

```
richTextBox0A.Text = Buffer[0].ToString("X2"); //Show Hex value
richTextBox0B.Text = Convert.ToString(Buffer[0], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');//Show binary value

richTextBox1A.Text = Buffer[1].ToString("X2");
richTextBox1B.Text = Convert.ToString(Buffer[1], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');

richTextBox2A.Text = Buffer[2].ToString("X2");
richTextBox2B.Text = Convert.ToString(Buffer[2], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
.
.
.
.
richTextBox149A.Text = Buffer[149].ToString("X2");
richTextBox149B.Text = Convert.ToString(Buffer[149], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Is it possible to perform the above commands like in bellow:

```
for (int i=0; i < 150; i++) {
    richTextBox0<i>A.Text = Buffer[i].ToString("X2");
    richTextBox1<i>B.Text = Convert.ToString(Buffer[i], 2).PadLeft(8,'0');
}
```

Or put them in an array and loop the array content?

Comment: You should put them in an array.

Comment: "them" == references to those 300 or so RTBs

Comment: How to put them in array?

Comment: This seems like a poor design for the form, where databinding or a custom control would have made this a lot simpler.

Comment: @ Joel Coehoorn I am using the form to read data from a serial port and data should be extracted and  shown all at the same time, I am not professional in C# but I think I am using a simplest way! thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i=0; i < 150; i++)
{
    var rtbA = (this.Controls.Find("richTextBox" + i + "A", true).FirstOrDefault() as RichTextBox);
    var rtbB = (this.Controls.Find("richTextBox" + i + "B", true).FirstOrDefault() as RichTextBox);

    if (rtbA == null || rtbB == null)
    {
        continue;
    }

    rtbA.Text = Buffer[i].ToString("X2");
    rtbB.Text = Convert.ToString(Buffer[i], 2).PadLeft(8,'0');
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, as it does not require duplicating the storage of the text boxes in an array.  However, I would suggest adding a null check before accessing the `.Text` property, or creating an `UpdateTextBoxIfExists` method that does the `this.Controls.Find... as RichTextBox` and then only attempts to update the `Text` property if the `RichTextBox` is non-null.

Comment: @selami thanks for the answer but i got the following problem: Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null conversion

Comment: @Majidff I add FirstOrDefault function. Find returns an array.